# What am I wrong with in my regular expression?

Tags: javascript

I have my next regular expression, but when I use it, it does not do what it should:

```
(([0-9]){1,}\.{0,1}){0,}
```

link: https://regex101.com/r/UVzc1U/3

I want the match to be dynamic because I want to capture routes of accounting accounts for example:

```
2.3
5.4.3
8.1.1.2
2.3.7.2.10
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: it works what is the problem ?

Comment: `{0,}` is also known as `*`, `{1,}` as `+`, and `{0,1}` as `?`. Using those shortcuts will make the expression clearer.

Comment: Is the problem that you want to match each number separately? Simplifying down to `(\d+\.?)` means you get one match for each number+decimal point.

Comment: at the moment of using it in an input it does not do what it should, in this other page and it marks me an error: the expression can match 0 characters, and therefore matches infinitely https://www.regextester.com/index.php?fam=102843

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to use `split()` (for example `'6.5.6'.split('.')` returns `["6", "5", "6"]`) then test each value is numbers `value.test(/[0-9]+/)`. That will work for codes like '005' and fails for anything odd (including the empty string '').